# In lock-screen it shows 16.04 but in `About this Computer' it is showing 15.10 version?

Tags: updates, 16.04, update-manager

I upgraded my Ubuntu using the terminal command `sudo apt-get upgrade` everything gone right, but in lock-screen it shows 16.04 LTS and in `About this Computer' it is showing 15.10 version?

Here the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lsb_release -a` to your question.

Comment: @Akshay Please use the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/788501/edit) function to include information into your answer, not use comments for that. I've included your information into your question for now and you can remove this comment. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of "About this Computer" showing 15.10?